# Getting permission error with rewrite rules within Azure web app

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a Laravel 4 based PHP application that I have successfully gotten working within an Azure web app, the only issue that I am having is when attempting to access files from `example.azurewebsites.net/js/vendor/jquery.slicknav.min.js` I get a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." Response.

The folder `site/wwwroot` is where I place all my Laravel application files, for those not familiar with Laravel it contains four folders: app, Bootstrap, public, and vendor.

I have set the **Virtual applications and directories** setting in the Azure portal to map `/` to `site\wwwroot\public` and placed within the public directory a web.config file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Laravel4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>    
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this set up the rewrite works as expected except when the folder name includes either app, Bootstrap, public, or vendor as it does with `example.azurewebsites.net/js/vendor/jquery.slicknav.min.js`.

My question is how do I amend my rewrite rules to fix this issue? If I rename the folder `site\wwwroot\public\js\vendor\` by adding a hyphen to the end, it will work. I have also rebooted the container multiple times.

**Edit** For more clarity this is my directory structure:

```
├─ wwwroot
│  └─ app
│  └─ bootstrap
│  ├─ public
│  │  └─ css
│  │  └─ files
│  │  └─ fonts
│  │  └─ imgs
│  │  ├─ js
│  │  │  └─ admin
│  │  │  ├─ app
│  │  │  │  └─ link-check.js
│  │  │  └─ old
│  │  │  ├─ vendor
│  │  │  │  └─ sortable.min.js
│  │  └─ less
│  │  └─ packages
│  │  └─ tmp
│  │  └─ uploads
│  └─ vendor
└─ ...
```

With my `web.config` configuration `link-check.js` is accessible via `example.azurewebsites.net/js/app/link-check.js` while sortable.min.js is **not** accessible via `example.azurewebsites.net/js/vendor/sortable.min.js` (and nothing else within the /js/vendor path is accessible).

Note: if I rename `wwwroot\public\js\vendor` to `wwwroot\public\js\vendor-` I can view `sortable.min.js` from `example.azurewebsites.net/js/vendor-/sortable.min.js`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out the reason for all folders with `vendor` in the path returning a 403 forbidden was that I had the [Azure composer web app extension installed](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension). Within the `applicationHost.xdt` file for that extension it sets the following rewrite:

```
<rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="vendor/(.*)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission to     view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied." />
            </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

For me removing the extension obviously fixed the problem, however I have a feeling that adding a `<clear/>` to my rewrite rules section would clear the rules set by the extension and fix the issue.

For future reference this issue was raised against the extension on [7th Nov 2015](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension/issues/10) and on the [23rd July 2015](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension/issues/6).

#### Below shows my amended web.config that uses `<clear/>` to fix the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <clientCache httpExpires="Sun, 29 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
        </staticContent>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,PATCH" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear/>
                <rule name="Laravel4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>    
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following steps:

- modify the setting in **Virtual applications and directories** section back to mapping `/` to `site\wwwroot\`
- move your `web.config` in the `public` folder to the root directory which may be the `site\wwwroot` in your server.
- modify the `web.config` content to the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)"
                  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(img|css|files|js|favicon.ico)(.*)$" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                                matchType="IsFile" 
                                ignoreCase="false" 
                                negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                                matchType="IsDirectory" 
                                ignoreCase="false" 
                                negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I still get the 403 error, and with that config I get additional 404 errors, which I am able to tidy up. Its the 403 permission denied on files that exist. I thought it might be because a folder called vendor exists outside of the configured virtual directory, but app and admin also do and they work. I am amending my question with my directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

I added clear inside of webconfig and worked for me.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
         <clear/>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```